# How to use std::cout in Visual Studio C++ Debug Immediate Window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Given following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()

{

    std::cout << 5 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

}
```

I set a breakpoint at the second `cout` and in Immediate Window, I tried

```cpp
std::cout<<5<<std::endl;
```

It says:

```
identifier "std::cout" is undefined
```

My main goal is to `cout` a variable. For simple variable like `int, double`, directly type the name can print it's value. However for more complex data structure like `Eigen::Matrix, boost::json::object, torch::Tensor`, `cout` will be needed. If I can't use `cout` in Immediate Window, I have to write `cout` in code, and rebuild the project which is inconvenient.

Comment: The immediate window is not a full-blown C++ interpreter. Its functionality and usefulness is limited.

Comment: Immediate Window is not supposed to execute C++ code at all, it is used to control debugger.

Comment: Did you type the question mark befire the expression?

Comment: Were you in the process of debugging this program, such that `std::cout` would be defined?

Comment: @n.m. @Drew Dormann, I want to use `cout` to print value of a variable in immediate window. Otherwise I have to write `std::cout` in code and rerun which is not convenient. Type the question mark doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You didn't answer... were you stopped at a breakpoint when you tried this?

Comment: @n.m. Yes I set a breakpoint at the second `cout`.

Comment: @user7860670 the first sentence in the manual is "Use the Immediate window to debug and evaluate expressions, execute statements, and print variable values".

Comment: @paddy I find that I can use simple functions like `sqrt<int, 0>(5)` so I'm wondering if cout is also permitted.

Comment: I can confirm, this indeed doesn't work. Even of we coerce VS to know about `std::out` (say by writing a function that returns a reference to it) it still cannot resolve `operator<<`. It's a debugger, not a full blown C++ interpreter (it *should* also be a full blown C++ interpreter, but it isn't, it is what it is).

Comment: @n.m. Yes you are right. I feel that lacking interactivity sometimes make C++ inconvenient.

Comment: Operator overloading is not supported in the immediate window. Honestly, if you need a language interpreter as a scratchpad, use Python or something. C++ is not that kind of language. Unfortunately you must reach a certain level of competence in C++ before you understand _why_ it's not interpreted, and then you'd never consider wishing for that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with a partial solution. First create a function return `string` and then call it in Immediate Window. In debug mode:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<Eigen/Core>
template<typename T>
std::string str(const T& v)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << v << std::endl;
    return ss.str();
}

template std::string str<Eigen::MatrixXf>(const Eigen::MatrixXf& v);
int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXf m(3, 3);
    std::cout << str(m) << std::endl; //Set a breakpoint here.
}
```

Then in Immediate Window:

```
str<Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,0,-1,-1> >(m)
```

Will print the result string. Note the blank space in `> >`. The symbol `str<Eigen::Matrix<float,-1,-1,0,-1,-1> >` can be find in `Disassembly` window.

It seems that we can call a function which has an address. If it has been optimized then we can't call it.

---

After some tests, I find that if there a member function return a string, then I can directly call the member:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
struct A
{
    int y = 5;
    std::string str() { return std::to_string(y); }
};
int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout << a.str() << std::endl;
}
```

Set a breakpoint at the `cout`, then in Immediate Window, I can call

```
a.str()
```

But this still doesn't fully achieve my goal.

Answer (score -1):

To print in immediate window:

1. Set `Redirect all output window text to the immediate window` in Tools-> Options ->Debugging-> General. Searching the option through `Visual Studio Search` will be more convenient.
2. #include<windows.h>
3. Use [OutputDebugStringA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-outputdebugstringa) in the snippet.

To check the variable's value: add break point and right click the variable->add watch. See [Watch variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2022)